# Angular 4 RouterModule

Tags: angular

I have some issue when i try to add RouterModule on my application. 
After i added router system on my app.module.ts file. i got this error again and again:

`compiler.es5.js:1689 Uncaught Error: RouterModule cannot be used as an entry component.`

Also here is my app.module.ts code:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule  }   from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './components/contact.component';

const appRoutes : Routes = [
    { path: 'test1', component : ContactComponent}  
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ContactComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, RouterModule]
 })
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove RouterModule from bootstrap

```
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `RouterModule` from `AppModule`'s `bootstrap` array:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ContactComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent <-- only AppComponent should be in boostrap array
  ]
 })
export class AppModule { }
```

I'm curious, why did you add it to `bootstrap` array in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Its a blunder though, You need to use like this.

```
  bootstrap: [AppComponent] // <== Remove RouterModule from here
```

You must not add any `Modules`, `Services`, `Directives`, `Pipes` in  `bootstrap` (The bootstrap array).

`bootstrap` — The root AppComponent that Angular creates and inserts into the index.html host web page.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent // Components, Services, Pipes
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule // Modules
  ],
  providers: [], // Services
  bootstrap: [AppComponent] // The root Component E.g. AppComponent
})
export class AppModule { }
```